# How to use sub domain in react?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote the react route code as below, everything works fine.

```
export const RoutePage = () => {
  return <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<DefaultLayout/>}>
        <Route path='/' element={<Main />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<RegisterPage />} />
        <Route path='/mypage' element={<MyPage />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />}/>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
}
```

However, there is a situation where a subdomain is required, how to set up a subdomain in this case?

In the current state, if you connect to localhost:3000/myinfo, you will be connected to the page, but,

If I connect to admin.localhost:3000/myinfo, I should be connected to another page. What should I do in this case?

Comment: It seems to me that for technical reasons this is impossible (at least, the browsers won't allow it). So you need either a second React application or the same application directly, but behind an Apache or Nginx reverse proxy. (Only in the case of the router). Your concern seems to me to be more related to the storage of data in the localStorage / cookies for the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you comfortable with DNS type A records?
If so, you can create a subdomain and point it to the same IP address as your react application.

For example:

your react application runs on this IP address: **127.0.0.1**

**your-domain.com** points to this IP address: **127.0.0.1**

**subdomain.your-domain.com** also points to this address: **127.0.0.1**

This way, I think **your-domain.com/myinfo** and **subdomain.your-domain.com/myinfo** will refer to the same route on your application.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to control the right page for each domain, I received good answers in the current post, but the method below was the best in my situation.

```
export const MainRoute = () => {
  return <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<DefaultLayout/>}>
        <Route path='/' element={<Main />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<RegisterPage />} />
        <Route path='/mypage' element={<MyPage />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />}/>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
}

export const ManagerRoute = () => {
  return <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundPage />}/>
    <Route element={<DefaultLayout/>}>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
}
```

I searched for the current connection url on the start page and connected the router suitable for the subdomain.

```
.....
const host = window.location.host.split(".")
  switch (host[0]) {
    case "manager":
      return <ManagerRoute />;      
    default:
      return <MainRoute />;
    }
}
```

I don't have much experience, but this answer gave me what I wanted without creating another project, if you have any other ideas please let me know thanks!